# Debian ignores /etc/sysctl.conf

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I have a problem with limiting the number of concurrent network connections. I just need to set them so that my machine will ***never produce*** more than 200 concurrent network connections, but I am unable to do so.

Here is my /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max=100
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_orphan_retries = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 25
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 150
```

I understand that this setting means that number of connections should not exceed 150 connections, but when, for example, I open many pages in firefox at same time, I can see that this setting is not respected - `netstat | grep tcp | wc -l` shows many more connections.

Here are some info about my system:

```
[firzen:~] lsb_release -sd
Debian GNU/Linux 7.7 (n/a)
[firzen:~] uname -r
3.2.0-2-686-pae
[firzen:~] arch
i686
```

How can I fix that? It is really a critical setting for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This has been asked before, see this post on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/10852/what-limits-the-maximum-number-of-connections-on-a-linux-server

Comment: Yes, but as you can see, I am using the same configuration (but with different values), and in my case it just does not work. And that is my problem.

Comment: No you are not using the same configuration. You should have limited the port range, as in net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    61000 This is very wide, suitable to the OP I referenced above, you should restrict it to the number of multiple connections you intend to allow.

Comment: Well, i have added this line to my /etc/sysctl.conf but is still does not work. What can I do with that? ..

Comment: Did you verify your changes using `sysctl variable`, eg. `sysctl net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max` ?

Comment: I have tried that and it writes: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_max: No such file or direktory.. But I am really sure that /etc/sysctl.conf is configured well. Also I restarted PC after editing this file.. So what can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

As per kernel documentation:

> tcp_max_orphans - INTEGER
>   Maximal number of TCP sockets not attached to any user file handle, held by system.   If this number is exceeded orphaned connections are reset immediately and warning is printed. This limit exists only to prevent simple DoS attacks, you *must* not rely on this or lower the limit artificially, but rather increase it (probably, after increasing installed memory), if network conditions require more than default value, and tune network services to linger and kill such states more aggressively. Let me to remind again: each orphan eats up to ~64K of unswappable memory.

So no, this doesn’t limit the number of *open* connections. Instead, you’ll have to use IPTables somehow, because this is clearly a firewall concern.